# How to check if username exists

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

How to return 1 if username exists and 0 in other case? Here is what I've tried.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE UserName = @UserName and EmailID=@EmailID) 
    begin
      return 1;
    end
     else
      begin
    declare @CreatedOn datetime
    select @CreatedOn = getdate()
    insert into [User](UserName,Password,EmailID,ContactNo,CreatedOn) values(@UserName,@Password,@EmailID,@ContactNo,@CreatedOn)
```

Comment: Just to confirm, do you want to return 1 when the username exists or when the username and email exist? Your code suggests something different to the text.

Comment: This should work:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [User] WHERE (UserName= @UserName AND EmailId=@EmailId )

Returns 0 if doesnt exist, 1 or more if exists

Comment: But as @psych states, you're also creating if doesnt exist.

Comment: return 1 when when the username or email exist.....sorry i don know how to use out paramemeter to get out from this...can  u please me friends,,,,,

Comment: Username OR email, or username AND email?

Comment: Also, when you say 'return 1' - are you creating this SQL as a stored procedure and you actual want to return this, or do you mean something else?

Comment: above code doesnt return 1 or 0..it returning 2 and -1...how to do this using out paramemeter friend???

Comment: ya i created this as stored procedure from ui called this stored procedure..i just want to return 1 if username or email already exist otherwise return 0 how to do this using out paramemter or in some other way that u r convenient ???pls guide me

Comment: So you don't want to insert the user is they don't exist? I have updated my answer.

Comment: sorry  
its not working..my suggestion is that without using out parameter we cannot return value from stored procedure ..so please give some other coding using that or any other any that it working..pls tel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this query:

```
Select count(*) from [user] where  UserName = @UserName and EmailID=@EmailID
```

and if user name exists count(*) will be larger then 0

Comment: its not working..my suggestion is that without using out parameter we cannot return value from stored procedure ..so please give some other coding using that or any other any that it working..pls tel

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckUserExists
AS
    @UserName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Email NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [User] WHERE UserName = @UserName OR EmailID=@EmailID) 
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        RETURN 0    
    END
END
```

Comment: its not working..my suggestion is that without using out parameter we cannot return value from stored procedure ..so please give some other coding using that or any other any that it working..pls tel

Comment: So when you call exec CheckUserExists and pass in valid parameters you get a return or 2 or -1? 

That doesn't seem to make sense... Please ensure that you are calling the stored procedure from within SSMS and not from your code. 

Under what circumstances does it return 2 (or -1)?

Comment: This is the correct way to do it; it will/can never return 2 or -1, if your seeing those results you need to update your question with the method your using to execute & captrue the USP.

Comment: This would suggest that the issue is something you haven't posted as I believe my answer is correct. How are you calling the SP? Have you ensured you are calling the correct procedure?

Comment: Everything seems to suggest that you are not calling the SQL that you think, so double check to ensure that you are actually running what I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see a bigger problem here. you stated you want to know if the user exists or not. but the query shows a side affect, that if the user doesn't exist you will create the user in the same call. these should be separate sqlcommands. one for the query/reading and another for the command/insert.

to determine if the user exists a simple `select 1 from [users] where [username] = @user` should suffice. if any (1?) rows are returned the user exists, otherwise the user does not exist.

you can then issue the command to create the user

```
insert into [User](UserName,Password,EmailID,ContactNo,CreatedOn) values(@UserName,@Password,@EmailID,@ContactNo,getdate())
```

Comment: its not working..my suggestion is that without using out parameter we cannot return value from stored procedure ..so please give some other coding using that or any other any that it working..pls tel

Comment: out parameters are not required. use `ExecuteReader()` to get the results. I avoid out parameters at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [User] WHERE UserName = @UserName and EmailID=@EmailID) 
    begin
      return 1;
    end
     else
       return 0;
```

Comment: its not working..my suggestion is that without using out parameter we cannot return value from stored procedure ..so please give some other coding using that or any other any that it working..pls tel

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Execute the SP As*/
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CheckUserExists]
Select @return_value

/*STORED PROCEDURE*/
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckUserExists
AS
    @UserName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Password NVARCHAR(MAX)
    @EmailID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ContactNo NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [User] WHERE UserName = @UserName and EmailID=@EmailID) 
    BEGIN
      RETURN 1;
    END
     ELSE
      BEGIN
        DECLARE @CreatedOn DATETIME
        SELECT @CreatedOn = GETDATE()
        INSERT INTO [User](UserName,Password,EmailID,ContactNo,CreatedOn) 
        VALUES(@UserName,@Password,@EmailID,@ContactNo,@CreatedOn)
        RETURN 0;
END
```

Comment: its not working..my suggestion is that without using out parameter we cannot return value from stored procedure ..so please give some other coding using that or any other any that it working..pls tel

Comment: @giri Try to execute your Stored procedure from the SqlServer-Management-Studio ("Right Click" on Sp and "Execute") . Then  you you will see a code like given as below. 
DECLARE (at)return_value int
EXEC    (at)return_value = [dbo].[CheckUserExists]
Select (at)return_value;                           This is how values returned from sp are received outside. Here (a) => At the rate

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE CheckUserExists
AS
    @UserName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Email NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
declare @usercount int

```
Select @usercount = count(UserName) from [user] where  UserName = @UserName and EmailID=@EmailID

IF (@usercount = 1) 
BEGIN
    RETURN 1
END
ELSE BEGIN
    RETURN 0    
END
```

END